# Useful way for image clustering

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm a ML newbie, and for the first time I'm trying 
to do machine learning to my own handwriting.
Building a classifier.

I have enough pictures containing my handwriting and I have managed to separate characters from one another.
The result is that now I have around 25,000 samples of letters each is a 40X40 pixels image, In Binary - black or white.

The problem I'm trying to solve is the tagging of each picture, which now I do manually, but I think of a simpler solution to my problem must be exist out there.

What can be a way for solving this kind of problem in the machine learning world?
Did every picture in the MINST database tagged by someone manually?

Comment: Yes, every MNIST image was tagged manually, by a group of Phd students. I will rephrase your question - if there is a way to label images automatically, then why would you have to build your classifier in the first place? The labelling method would be the perfect classifier. Of course there are methods to help/speed things up, but in the end it requires a lot of manual work.

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to build a auto classifier to any handwriting, this will be an impossible task to accomplish, classifying every letter manually.
I'm thinking of something like what google photos are doing to pictures only for letters.
Does an auto encoder help in this area?

Comment: Again, you cannot avoid training set, this is simply impossible and defeats the whole purpose of supervised learning. There are many ways to be invariant to handwriting (the most common being having training set of various handwritings).